# Behavior of fgets(), newline character and how it gets stored in the memory

Tags: c, memory, fgets

I have this code below and I'm curious what would be stored in the memory if I entered

"Hi" then I'll press enter, will 'H' 'i' '\n' '\0' be stored in the memory

and if I enter

"Hello" then I'll press enter, will 'H' 'e' 'l' 'l' '\0' be stored in the memory then 'o' '\n' be in the buffer

and lastly, if I enter

"Hell" then I'll press enter, will 'H' 'e' 'l' 'l' '\0' be stored in the memory then '\n' be in the buffer

```
char str [5];

fgets(str, 5, stdin);
printf("%s", str);
```

Comment: Calling `fflush` with an input-only stream (like `stdin`) is explicitly mentioned in the C specifications as *undefined behavior*. Some implementations add it as a non-portable extension.

Comment: As for your problem, you could simply try it out, printing the contents of the array, character by character after each attempt. Or use a debugger to step over the `fgets` call and then check the contents of the array. Generally speaking, it should be as you seem to guess already.

Comment: Maybe just look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/). (Any answer that I could post would be, at best, a mildly plagiarized version of that!)

Comment: "will 'H' 'i' '\n' '\0' be stored in the memory" --> Yes.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica , how about Hell and Hello? Is my understanding of those correct?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude , what would be a recommended alternative for fflsuh?

Comment: Yes, except for the `fflush(stdin)` part.  Who or what text suggested `fflush(stdin)`?

Comment: Read character by character until you get a newline.

Comment: @AdrianMole , sadly it doesn't say anything about the unread characters

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica , my programming professors suggested it, maybe because its still an introductory programming class?

Comment: Janjan, "programming professors suggested it" --> Unfortunately some professors are not up-to-date with good programming practices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fgets(buf, n, stream)` reads input and saves it into `buf` until 1 of 4 things happen.

- Buffer is nearly full.  Once n-1 characters read (and saved), `'\0'` is appended to `buf`.  Function returns `buf`.  There is likely remaining characters in `stream` to read.<sup>1</sup>
- `'\n'` is read from `stream`.  `'\n'` is appended to `buf`. `'\0'` is appended to `buf`.  Function returns `buf`.  The *line* has been completely read.
- End-of-file occurs. Had some characters been read before, `'\0'` is appended to `buf`.  Function returns `buf`.  Else `NULL` is returned.
- Input error (rare).  `NULL` is returned.  state of `buf` is indeterminate.

The only thing different about reading `'\n'` versus other characters is that it informs  `fgets()` to stop reading.

---

<sup>1</sup> Should a full buffer get read without `'\n'`, to read and toss the rest of the *line*:

```
int ch;
while ((ch = fgetc(stream)) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
  ;
}
```

Comment: What if in the case of exactly n-1 character then I clicked enter on my keyboard? Will the newline char remain in the buffer or stored in the memory as 'a'....'n-1' '\n' and the newline char replaced with a null byte or will it store 'a'....'n-1' '\0' and leave the newline char in the buffer

Comment: @Janjan "newline char replaced with a null byte" is incorrect.  See "The only thing different about reading '\n'...." above.  The Enter key generates `'\n'` - that is a character too.  Is `'\n'` one of the `n-1 characters in your question?

Comment: I mean no disrespect but is the answer provided by anastaciu in the comments incorrect? "Yes, as you input "Hell" followed by enter the buffer will have "H e l l \n" so when it's stored, '\n' will be replaced by '\0'."

Comment: Yep, I immediately realized my mistake haha

Comment: Does this mean that "Hell" then I'll press enter, will 'H' 'e' 'l' 'l' '\0' be stored in the memory then '\n' be in the buffer is correct. While 'H' 'e' 'l' 'l' '\n'  stored in the memory however \n will be replaced with \0 making it H e l l \0 is incorrect

Comment: @Janjan That comment is amiss.  With a short buffer it is _as if_ \n was replaced with \0, with \n still in the stream, yet a better way to look at it is that characters pass n-1 are not read (\n or otherwise), a \0 is appended and fgets() returns like the first bullet of this answer.

Comment: I have tried using two fgets both reading an n of 5, while I entered Hell and clicked enter both of it are executed. Does it mean that my original understanding that \n is left in the buffer is correct? Did I undersrand correctly this time?

Comment: Appears correct.  The first `fgets(buf, 5, stdin)` read the first 4 of the 5 characters, H,e,l,l,\n.  \n remains in `stdin`  The 2nd  `fgets(buf, 5, stdin)` reads the \n and stops.

Comment: Thank you very much, so my original assumption was indeed correct. Kindly please answer this with jusg a yes or no, I just want an assurance haha.

Comment: @Janjan Too much unclear about what your original assumption were and your understanding now.  Let us focus on code.

Comment: This one: if I input
"Hell" then press enter, 'H' 'e' 'l' 'l' '\0' be stored in the memory then '\n' be in the buffer.

Comment: With `n==5`, yes. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60509461/behavior-of-fgets-newline-character-and-how-it-gets-stored-in-the-memory/60510945?noredirect=1#comment107049610_60510945)

Comment: Thank you! Now I fully understand what fgets does. Thank you!!!

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, I've read this interesting exchange and I would like to ask you, do you mean that if the size of the inputed string is equal to the size of the container, \n included, \n will reamain in the buffer, what about if I input "Hel" for this specific case? Can you point me to any docs that standardize this behaviour?

Comment: @anastaciu  `'\n'` remains in `stdin` in first case.  Perhaps "The fgets function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by n from the stream pointed to by stream into the array pointed to by s. No additional characters are read after a new-line character (which is retained) or after end-of-file. A null character is written immediately
after the last character read into the array."  C17 § 7.21.7.2 2

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, thanks for your reply, that clarifies things.

Answer (score 2):

Given the definition of `fgets()`:

> `char *fgets( char *str, int count, FILE *stream );`
>           (until C99)
>
> `char *fgets( char *restrict str, int count, FILE *restrict stream );`
>           (since C99)
>
> Reads at most `count - 1` characters from the given file stream and stores them in the character `array` pointed to by `str`. Parsing stops if a `newline` character is found, in which case `str` will contain that `newline` character, or if `end-of-file` occurs. If bytes are read and no errors occur, writes a `null character` at the position immediately after the last character written to `str`.
>
> The behavior is undefined if `count` is less than 1. It is also not specified whether a  `null` character is written if `count==1`.

`fgets` stores the inputed line with the maximum length (size) of 5 in the `str` variable and null terminates it.

Since the size you provide is 5, if you input `"Hello"` it will store `H e l l \0` replacing the `'o'`, `'o'` is not stored and, normally, `'o'` and `'\n'` will remain in the `stdin` buffer though this is not standard mandated.

If you intput `"Hell"` the `stdin` buffer will have `H e l l \n` so when its stored `'\n'` will be replaced by `'\0'`, and `'\n'` will remain in the buffer.

In the same way if the line is smaller than `5 - 1`, nothing is replaced, the `char array` is null terminated i.e. `"Hel"` will be stored as `H e l \n \0`, and the `stdin` buffer will be emptied.

This is why you normally declare your `char array` 1 char bigger than the actual max size expected, and pass its size to `fgets`:

```
fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
```

Note that [you should not use fflush(stdin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin).

Comment: "If you intput "Hell" then '\n' will be replaced by '\0'" , will this newline character be in the buffer waiting to be read?

Comment: Yes, as you input "Hell" followed by enter the buffer will have "H e l l \n" so when it's stored, '\n' will be replaced by '\0'.

Comment: So instead of storing \n, \0 will be stored then \n will be left in the buffer, am I right?

Comment: @Janjan, it will not, this will only happen if the string is bigger than 5, if you input "Hello", 'o' is replaced and '\n' will remain in the buffer.

Comment: May I ask why are there conflicting answers on this thread :(. Please see the answer of Samuel Peter. Sorry, i"m just really confused.

Comment: As far as I can tell Samuel Peter is correct the standard does not mandate it, but this is usually what happens.

Comment: So my interpretations as posted above are correct except when reading Hell? It should be "Hello" then I'll press enter, 'H' 'e' 'l' 'l' '\n' be stored in the memory however \n will be replaced with \0 making it H e l l \0 ?

Comment: @Janjan Yes, that's it.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps up a lot :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208932/discussion-between-janjan-and-anastaciu).

Comment: May I request a chat with you, I may have some further clarifications

Comment: Detail: "fgets stores the inputed string" is not bad, yet conflagates _string_.  As C Lib has a specific meaning for _string_, that does not match what the user types (no \0).  `fgets()` is more like taking the user inputted _line_ and converting it to a _string_.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, Term correction is definately important, I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

From `man fgets` on my machine:

> `char * fgets(char * restrict str, int size, FILE * restrict stream);`
>
> The fgets() function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by `size` from the given `stream` and stores them in the string `str`. Reading stops when a newline character is found, at end-of-file or error.  The newline, if any, is retained.  If any characters are read and there is no error, a `\0' character is appended to end the string.

This means that you are correct about what will be stored in your `str` buffer. The unread characters can presumably be read by a subsequent read on stdin, but this will depend on the OS and where you are reading from. The C standard doesn't mandate it.

Comment: How about the newline characters and the way it is stored in memory? Is my interpretation of it correct?